# Write list of polynomials as a matrix of coefficients times a list of monomials

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the following problem: given a list of polynomials `P = {p1, ..., pn}` on the variables `x[1], ..., x[n]`, find a list of monic monomials `M = q1, ..., qm` on `x[1], ..., x[n]` and a matrix `A` that does not depend on `x[1], ..., x[n]` such that `A.M = P`.

For example, taking `P = {x[1] x[2] + x[1]^2 x[2], a x[1]^2 + b x[2], c x[1]^2 x[2] + d x[2]^2}` a possible solution is:

`M = {x[1] x[2], x[1]^2, x[2], x[2]^2, x[1]^2 x[2]}`,

`A = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, a, b, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, c, d}}`

I managed to find a long and clumsy solution by using a lot of replacement rules, but I want to know if there is an easy way of doing something like this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that might get you started. Will require some adjustment to get it exactly to what you want.

```
In[70]:= pP = {x[1] x[2] + x[1]^2 x[2], a x[1]^2 + b x[2], 
  c x[1]^2 x[2] + d x[2]^2}

Out[70]= {x[1] x[2] + x[1]^2 x[2], a x[1]^2 + b x[2], 
 c x[1]^2 x[2] + d x[2]^2}

In[78]:= vars = {x[1], x[2]};

In[84]:= mlist = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[pP, vars][[1]]

Out[84]= {{{{2, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}}, {{{2, 0}, a}, {{0, 1}, 
   b}}, {{{2, 1}, c}, {{0, 2}, d}}}

In[98]:= ml2 = 
 mlist /. {{e1_Integer, e2_Integer}, c_} :> {c, 
    Times @@ (vars^{e1, e2})}

Out[98]= {{{1, x[1]^2 x[2]}, {1, x[1] x[2]}}, {{a, x[1]^2}, {b, 
   x[2]}}, {{c, x[1]^2 x[2]}, {d, x[2]^2}}}

In[99]:= {aa, mm} = {ml2[[All, All, 1]], ml2[[All, All, 2]]}

Out[99]= {{{1, 1}, {a, b}, {c, d}}, {{x[1]^2 x[2], 
   x[1] x[2]}, {x[1]^2, x[2]}, {x[1]^2 x[2], x[2]^2}}}

In[100]:= MapThread[Dot, {aa, mm}]

Out[100]= {x[1] x[2] + x[1]^2 x[2], a x[1]^2 + b x[2], 
 c x[1]^2 x[2] + d x[2]^2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach based on `CoefficientRules`

```
P = {x[1] x[2] + x[1]^2 x[2], a x[1]^2 + b x[2], c x[1]^2 x[2] + d x[2]^2};
n = 2;
X = x /@ Range[n]
```

> ```
> {x[1], x[2]}
> ```

```
coeff = Thread@(# -> Range@Length[#]) &@ 
    Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ CoefficientRules[P, X][[All, All, 1]]]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1} -> 1, {0, 2} -> 2, {1, 1} -> 3, {2, 0} -> 4, {2, 1} -> 5}
> ```

```
M = Inner[Power, X, Transpose@coeff[[All, 1]], Times]
```

> ```
> {x[2], x[2]^2, x[1] x[2], x[1]^2, x[1]^2 x[2]}
> ```

```
A = SparseArray[Join @@ MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #[[1]]} -> #[[2]] &, 
      CoefficientRules[P, X] /. coeff, {2}]];

A.M == P
```

> True